# What should I do after I install 128 GB of storage on my android?

Tags: xiaomi-pocophone-f1, flashdrive

I install 128 GB extra storage on my android.

The thing is, most of those spaces are empty.

I cannot, for example, move my most space hoarding apps over there.

I can move files but I have no idea which file I should move.

My phone is POCO X3 NFC

I am using MKIUI Global 12.0.7 Stable

Some says I should integrate the flash card with my normal ssd. However, I do not see such option in settings

I installed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd

It says I can move app but I need to format SD card as internal by going to

Settings > Storage > SD card

Well, in settings there is no menu called storage.

It seems that in APP there should be a button that say Change.

I see no such button.

[image]

I can go to manage apps and I am supposed to see this

[image]

I don't. My typical screen shen I click manage apps look like.

See. No change button. I should format my SD as internal. I do not see any such option. I can format my SD but there is no option that it's formatted as internal.
[image]

Comment: Why did you add 512GB of extra storage?  What function were you hoping to fulfill by doing so?

Comment: I added 128 GB. The internal storage is almost full.

Comment: So the device came with 384GB of storage?  With what is it filled?

Comment: formatting SD as [internal](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) is a waste of real internal storage, sure you want this?

Comment: the original storage is 128 GB. it's full often due to whatsapp getting big. So I add another SD card for extra space

Answer (score 3):

Your device comes with (fast) 64/128GB UFS Flash Storage. moving apps to (slow) MicroSD Card requires formatting as [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) (and makes Internal Storage unused).

In case you really need more storage for apps consider rooting your device. (Along with several disadvantages) you get ability for `mount`ing single apps to MicroSD Card manually.

[Partition MicroSD card to exFat and Ext 4 for link2sd?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189487/partition-microsd-card-to-exfat-and-ext-4-for-link2sd)
[How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/how-to-bind-mount-a-folder-inside-sdcard-with-correct-permissions)

Comment: Any easy way to make adoptable storage? I am using POCO

Comment: What do you mean by making internal storage unused? I want to use both internal storage. however, I want some apps to move to micro sd card.

Comment: the whole `/sdcard` is moved to adopted MicroSD card, it's either or

Comment: the [sm partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213312) commands should work to format as internal. check `df` when done. then try your app again

Comment: Say I have 128GB memory and 128 GB SD card, will I have 256 GB total space?

Comment: No. you will have 107G for apps and 119G for movable apps and media. so the max. pictures to be saved is 119G formatted as internal (compare: for portable storage the max. pictures to be saved is 226G)