# How to move most of my app in poco to sd card?

Tags: sd-card, poco-3

I bought SD card. However, the SD card is completely useless. I cannot move any apps to that.

Sure I can store some files there but that means it doesn't get filled automatically.

My main memory is filled with so many things which is why I bought that SD card.

I've heard that if I format the SD card in a certain way then I can move apps but I don't know how.

My smartphone is poco 3c

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info

Comment: And in any case it would be preferable to move your personal files (photos, music and video) to the new storage. Do that and you'll notice a huge difference. Poco C3 comes with 64GB internal storage which is PLENTY for the OS and hundreds of apps if not used to store user's garbage.

Comment: OP's previous question for additional context, I guess: [What should I do after I install 128 GB of storage on my android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247564/44325)

Comment: Not all apps. Just the big one. Basically using the SD card for something useful.

Comment: It looks like there is no easy way to add storage in POCO with MicroSD card. I can add extra files but I can't arrange that some applications are moved there. It's a very problematic design